# Error inflating class com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar

Tags: android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: 
com.example.liew.idelivery, PID: 19633 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo
{com.example.liew.idelivery/com.example.liew.idelivery.FoodList}: 
android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class 
com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: 
Error inflating class com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar          
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
com.example.liew.idelivery.FoodList.onCreate(FoodList.java:47) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2462)at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2534)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:964)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: 
Error inflating class com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView
(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.liew.idelivery.FoodList.onCreate(FoodList.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
atandroid.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView
(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at com.example.liew.idelivery.FoodList.onCreate(FoodList.java:47) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2415) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID 
#0xff000000
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1333)
at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:963)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
(ContextCompat.java:420)
at com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar.setupTextColors
(MaterialSearchBar.java:187)
at com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar.postSetup
(MaterialSearchBar.java:177)
at com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar.init
(MaterialSearchBar.java:133)
at com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar.<init>
```

(MaterialSearchBar.java:77)

I did not display the full logcat as it is too long. The error occur when i declare app:mt_textColor="#000000" , i knew there are something wrong in the FoodList.java which is at the part

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);
```

FoodList.java

```
package com.example.liew.idelivery;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Model.Food;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.ViewHolder.FoodViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference foodList;
String categoryId="";
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,FoodViewHolder> adapter;

//searchbar functionality
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,FoodViewHolder> searchAdapter;
List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);


    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    foodList = database.getReference("Food");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //get intent here
    if(getIntent() != null)
        categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
    if(!categoryId.isEmpty() && categoryId != null){

        loadListFood(categoryId);
    }

    //search
    materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar)findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    materialSearchBar.setHint("Enter your food");

    // write function to load suggest from firebase
    loadSuggest();

    materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //when user type their text, we will change suggest list
            List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String search:suggestList){ // loop in suggest list

                if(search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                    suggest.add(search);
            }
             materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
            //when search bar is closed
            //restore original adapter

            if(!enabled)
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            //when search finish
            //show result of search adapter

            startSearch(text);

        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

        }
    });

}

private void startSearch(CharSequence text) {

    searchAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(
            Food.class,
            R.layout.food_item,
            FoodViewHolder.class,
            foodList.orderByChild("Name").equalTo(text.toString()) //compared name
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {

            viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);

            final Food local = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    //start new activity
                    Intent foodDetail = new Intent(FoodList.this, FoodDetail.class);
                    foodDetail.putExtra("FoodId", searchAdapter.getRef(position).getKey()); //send FoodId to new activity
                    startActivity(foodDetail);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    //set adapter for recycle view is search result
    recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
}

private void loadSuggest() {

    foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Food item = postSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

                // add food name to suggest list
                suggestList.add(item.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(Food.class,
            R.layout.food_item,
            FoodViewHolder.class,
            foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId) //select food from menuId
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {

            viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);

            final Food local = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    //start new activity
                    Intent foodDetail = new Intent(FoodList.this, FoodDetail.class);
                    foodDetail.putExtra("FoodId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey()); //send FoodId to new activity
                    startActivity(foodDetail);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //set adapter

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );
}
}
```

activity_food_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FoodList"
>

<com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:mt_hint="Enter your food"
    app:mt_speechMode="false"
    app:mt_textColor="#000000"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_food"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: does `com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar` exist this class ?

Comment: i got declare in XML file and yea it exist

Comment: share this class!

Comment: refer to activity_food_list.xml

Comment: @HemantParmar do u have any clue to solve this ?

Comment: solved with adding app:mt_searchBarColor="@color/colorPrimary" to change the search bar color